# Android wear: keeping display on

Tags: java, android

On my watchface I need sometimes do wait a relative long time for data. During this wait cycle I think, it would be nice to keep the display on.
Unfortunately I didn't got it running with the same way I got it on my mobile phone (using PowerManager.WakeLock).

Can someone suggest me a right way to do that?

Thanks a lot
Luca

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it with PowerManager...
I just forgot to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

to my AndroidManifest.xml... :(

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Use Window flag: as long as this window is visible to the user, keep the device's screen turned on and bright.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

If it doesn't work check this link [Keep your app visible on Wear](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on#ConfigureProject) It might help you.